# Reducing gap in the DatagridView's panel

Tags: vb.net, basic

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGQWw.png)

The dgv Inside the blue panel should be maximized in without any gap

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    If Not ValidateInput(CtrlDtl) Then Return
    If Not ValidateAddItem() Then Return

    AddRecord()
    ClearDetails()
    CalculateTotal()
    txtAmtWithGst.Select()

    With PanelDgvDocDtl
        .Size = New Size(dgvKnockOff.Width * 0.415, dgvKnockOff.Height - 24)
        Panel2.Height = .Height
        .Location = New Point(dgvKnockOff.Right - PanelDgvDocDtl.Width, pnlTop.Height + 25)
        .BringToFront()
    End With

    'this is my code that set size and location for the dgv

    PanelDgvDocDtl.Visible = True
    If dgvDocDtl.Rows.Count > 1 Then cmbBranchCode.Enabled = False

    clearMode = False 'setting the clear mode false to prevent certain control from being cleared, 
    Clear() 'maybe there is a better way to handle this
    clearMode = True 'setting it true. so the clear() method can clear all the controls it has. for other flow - agaesh

    pnlTotal.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please look at the preview of your question before submitting and don't submit if the formatting is a mess. Also, you seem to have uploaded an image but it's not it can't be seen, so what use is it? It's not hard to make sure your question looks right before posting it.

Comment: As with any child control, you can use the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties to control how it resizes relative to its parent. If you want the edges of the grid to stay a fixed distance from the edges of the parent container, set that spacing in the designer and then set the `Anchor` property to include that edge. Simples.